# attachment_fu and multipart form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multipart, attachment-fu

Woo. My first question.

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something pretty basic in the construction of my form. I'm using attachment_fu and can't get this form to pass anything besides the file data. A user has_many profiles and a profile has_many documents.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= error_messages_for :document %>

<% form_for([@user, @profile, @document], :html => {:multipart => true }) do |f| -%>
  <p>
    <label for="document">Upload A document:</label>
    <%= f.file_field :uploaded_data %>
  </p>
 <%= f.label :description%>
 <%= f.text_field :description%>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag 'Upload' %>
  </p>
<% end -%>
```

And here's the controller:

```
  before_filter :require_user, :get_profile

  def new
    @document = @profile.documents.build
  end

  def create
    @document = @profile.documents.build(params[:document])

    if @document.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Your document was successfully created.'
      redirect_to document_url(@document)     
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  private

  def get_profile
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:profile_id])
  end
```

The logs show all the image data getting posted, but I cannot pass the description or, more importantly, the profile_id, which is the foreign key in my document model. I was stuck on this all night, and can't think of anything fresh this morning. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `profile_id` you will need something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :profile_id %>
```

Which in your controller you will get at using `params[:document][:profile_id]` if needed.
Although from trying to guess at what your code is doing, I suspect that `params[:profile_id]` is already set from whatever route got you to this controller.

I am not sure why you aren't seeing anything for the description. It should be coming into your controller as `params[:document][:description]`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. You're right, profile_id is set through the routes. 

After some more looking/playing around I think it has something to do with the attachment_fu plugin and the way it defends against mass assignment: https://ar-code.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35/tickets/37-mass-assignment-attr_accessible

I'm still not sure exactly how to handle it, but it's a start...

Comment: Not sure if you have any specific requirements for attachment_fu, but you might find paperclip easier to deal with: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Played around with attachment_fu for another few hours, thought I had something, but didn't. Paperclip was stupid-simple to get going, thanks for the tip.